# Passing the value of an HTML form to another form

Tags: html, forms

I have a HTML form which allows a radio button selection of two products.  After the product is selected, the user has the option of digital download or delivery of which there is a separate form for each asking different questions.

I need to ensure that the product selection is passed to either of the two form for when the user makes the decision on which delivery option to opt for.  Only one of the forms is submitted.

Basically I have:

Form1: Product Selection Radio Button (2 Options)

// Choice of delivery options hidden by a javascript reveal of the relevant form

Form2a: Digital download form fields with actions for validation and submission to Paypal

Form2b: Regualar delivery form fields with actions for validation and submission to Paypal

I look forward to a solution from the excellent minds on this site!

Comment: What language/tools are you using on the server side?... Edit: Scratch that question - I assume this is all on a single page?

Comment: You need to provide many more details if you expect a decent answer.  See the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is all on a single page, it sounds like you don't really need multiple forms. I would suggest just including everything in a single form, wrapping the applicable questions for each selection in separate <div> tags and using some JavaScript to present the applicable <div> when either radio button is selected. When the form is submitted, check the radio button selection on the server side to determine which other form fields to utilise.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am kind of already doing this however my client is insisting on multiple forms which isn't really the way I would have done it if it was up to me...basically the forms are on the same page but revealed with JavaScript once the delivery selection has been chosen.  The selection is made by an image, not a form.

Comment: Curious to know why your client is being so prescriptive about the solution, but it doesn't much matter whether you use one form or two in reality. If you use two forms, then you can just identify the delivery method using a hidden input tag with the same name and different values in each form (or use different action URLs for each form of course). Referring back to your original query, there is no need to 'pass' the product selection to the forms, since this is inherent in which form is submitted anyway.